# Parse emails from Address Book

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Our application has an invite page where a user can import their address book. We're using an external service to get at them, so it just puts the results into a textarea. We started out just splitting the results by comma, and quickly figured out that wasn't going to work because of:

```
"Smith, Joe" <jsmith@example.com>, "Jackson, Joe" <jjackson@example.com>
```

It would work between the 2 entries, but also split inside them as well. Just wondering if there's a well known fool-proof way to make this work.

Maybe regex would work? I'm pretty bad that, could anyone tip me off to what regex would extract just the emails into an array...

Something like this:

```
emails = recipients.scan(/.*@.*/) <<==== but i know that's not right
```

EDIT

Looks like something like this might work. Anyone have any suggestions if this would work for special cases:

```
emails = recipients.scan(/[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z.]+/i)
```

Comment: Treat them as quoted CSV data, maybe...

Comment: So you don't care about the names, you just want to extract the email addresses?

Comment: That's right. I have this, which seems to catch everything I send to it:

/[a-z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+.[a-z.0-9-]+/i

Comment: Watch out for plus signs in the address, `a+b@example.com` is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :055 >   a = '"Smith, Joe" <jsmith@example.com>, "Jackson, Joe" <jjackson@example.com>';
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :056 >   b = a.scan(/<(.*?)>/).flatten
 => ["jsmith@example.com", "jjackson@example.com"] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :057 > c = a.scan(/"(.*?)"/).flatten
 => ["Smith, Joe", "Jackson, Joe"]
```

The index of name / email in each array is the same, thus c[1] is the name for the b[1] email.

Based on your comment how about his :

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :008 > a = '"Smith, Joe" <jsmith@example.com>, "Jackson, Joe" <jjackson@example.com>';
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :009 >   b = '"test@domain.com, test2@domain.com"';
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :010 >   b.scan(/\w*@\w*\.\w*/)
 => ["test@domain.com", "test2@domain.com"] 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :011 > a.scan(/\w*@\w*\.\w*/)
 => ["jsmith@example.com", "jjackson@example.com"]
```

Which is pretty much the same as you added to your question, just more compact.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that the format could be combined with simple "test@domain.com, test2@domain.com" (doesn't have the < > ) and that wouldn't hold up. I think I found a regex that will pull out the emails properly, but stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question yet.

Comment: scan(/\w*@\w*\.\w*/) doesn't work for mail address like "first.last@gmail.com"

Answer (score 3):

Kassym's version will fail in all sorts of circumstances, including on any email addresses that contain non-word characters (eg `some.guy@gmail.com`)

Parsing email lists can't be done with regular expressions. Use something with a real parser, like the [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem:

```
require "mail"

Mail::AddressList.new(address_list).addresses.map(&:address)
```

EZ!

Comment: This seems like a great suggestion.  Is it worth incorporating this entire gem into just parsing the email addresses though?  That's all I need for my application at the moment and I'm wondering if I should include this in my Gemfile or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split with the following regex

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Altho this is not an optimal quick solution, and could be slow for longs strings, better to use a specialized parser. Quoted quotes could be a problem with this solution, depending on how they are escaped (if at all).